# Select all Checkbox for editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I Want to edit all the table row items at once using Select all function in jquery but when I click select all it was not showing dropdown but when I click individual checkbox I can see dropdown in first row

Select all is working fine but it was not effecting row
Reference Image when I select all [image: Select ALL]
Reference Image when I select single [image: Single]

What I want is when I click select all I want the table to be show dropdown.

HTML Code

```
   
   <html>  
    <head>  
        <title>Payment Desk</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
          
    </head>  
    <body>  
       <?php include('includes/header.php');?>
    <!-- LOGO HEADER END-->
<?php if($_SESSION['login']!="")
{
 include('includes/menubar.php');
} 
     
 ?>
        <div class="container">  
            <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">  
    <h3 align="center">Payment Desk</h3><br />
    <form method="post" id="update_form">
                    <div align="left">
                        <input type="submit" name="multiple_update" id="multiple_update" class="btn btn-info" value="Pay" />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                       
                       
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <th width="5%"><input id="checkall" type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)"></th>
                                <th width="25%">Staus</th>
                                <th width="20%">Cheque No</th>
                                <th width="10%">Bank Book Amount</th>
                                <th width="25%">Bank Statement Amount</th>
                                <th width="20%">Bank Statement Ref No</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </form>
   </div>  
  </div>
    </body>  
</html>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    
    function fetch_data()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"cheque_select.php",
            method:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            data:{'bank': "<?php echo $bank ; ?>",'banktype': "<?php echo $banktype ; ?>"},
            
            success:function(data)
            {
                
                var html = '';
                for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
                {
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+data[count].id+'" data-status="'+data[count].status+'" data-cheque_no="'+data[count].cheque_no+'" data-iii="'+data[count].iii+'" data-credit="'+data[count].credit+'" data-ref="'+data[count].ref+'" class="check_box"  /></td>';
                    html += '<td>Not Matched</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].cheque_no+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].iii+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].credit+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].ref+'</td></tr>';
                }
                $('tbody').html(html);
            }
        });
    }

    fetch_data();

    $(document).on('click', '.check_box', function(){
        var html = '';
        if(this.checked)
        {
            html = '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" data-status="'+$(this).data('status')+'" data-cheque_no="'+$(this).data('cheque_no')+'" data-iii="'+$(this).data('iii')+'" data-credit="'+$(this).data('credit')+'" data-ref="'+$(this).data('ref')+'" class="check_box" checked /></td>';
            html += '<td><select name="status[]" id="status_'+$(this).attr('id')+'" class="form-control"><option value="1">Matched</option><option value="0">Not Matched</option></select><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id[]" value="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" /><input type="hidden" name="gghh[]" value="'+$(this).data('cheque_no')+'" /></td>';
            html += '<td>'+$(this).data('cheque_no')+'</td>';
            html += '<td>'+$(this).data('iii')+'</td>';
            html += '<td>'+$(this).data('credit')+'</td>';
            html += '<td>'+$(this).data('ref')+'</td>';
            
        }
        else
        {
            html = '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" data-status="'+$(this).data('status')+'" data-cheque_no="'+$(this).data('cheque_no')+'" data-iii="'+$(this).data('iii')+'" data-credit="'+$(this).data('credit')+'" data-ref="'+$(this).data('ref')+'" class="check_box" /></td>';
            html += '<td>Not Matched</td>';  
            html += '<td>'+$(this).data('cheque_no')+'</td>';
            html += '<td>'+$(this).data('iii')+'</td>';
            html += '<td>'+$(this).data('credit')+'</td>';
            html += '<td>'+$(this).data('ref')+'</td>';
                      
        }
        $(this).closest('tr').html(html);
        $('#sum_'+$(this).attr('id')+'').val($(this).data('sum'));
    });

    $('#update_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($('.check_box:checked').length > 0)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"multiple_update.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:$(this).serialize()+'&'+$.param({'bank': "<?php echo $bank ; ?>"}),
                success:function()
                {
                    alert('Data Updated');
                    fetch_data();
                }
            })
        }
    });

});  
    
    $('#checkall').change(function(){
        $('.check_box').prop("checked")
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.trigger('change')` to call your change event of checkboxes . Then , inside this event handler you can loop through your checkboxes and depending on this add select or normal text to your second *td* .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on('change', '.check_box', function() {
  //loop through each checkboxes...
  $(".check_box").each(function() {
    var html = '';
    if (this.checked) {
      //only add select-box
      html = '<select name="status[]" id="status_' + $(this).attr('id') + '" class="form-control"><option value="1">Matched</option><option value="0">Not Matched</option></select><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id[]" value="' + $(this).attr('id') + '" /><input type="hidden" name="gghh[]" value="' + $(this).data('cheque_no') + '" />';
    } else {
      html = 'Not Matched'; //only text
    }
    //get 2nd td add html there
    $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1)").html(html);
    $('#sum_' + $(this).attr('id') + '').val($(this).data('sum'));
  })
});

$('#checkall').change(function() {
  $('.check_box').prop("checked", this.checked).trigger('change')
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="update_form">
  <div align="left">
    <input type="submit" name="multiple_update" id="multiple_update" class="btn btn-info" value="Pay" />
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="table-responsive">


    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <th width="5%"><input id="checkall" type="checkbox"></th>
        <th width="25%">Staus</th>
        <th width="20%">Cheque No</th>
        <th width="10%">Bank Book Amount</th>
        <th width="25%">Bank Statement Amount</th>
        <th width="20%">Bank Statement Ref No</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="2" data-status="" data-cheque_no="11" data-iii="1" data-credit="3" data-ref="3" class="check_box"></td>
          <td>Not Matched</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="2" data-status="" data-cheque_no="11" data-iii="1" data-credit="2" data-ref="3" class="check_box"></td>
          <td>Not Matched</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="3" data-status="" data-cheque_no="11" data-iii="1" data-credit="2" data-ref="3" class="check_box"></td>
          <td>Not Matched</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```